# Jsp-servlet peer to peer chat application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i had done so far listed online users and just create chat window link for all listed users but i actually do not know how to display a popup chat window when a user send message to another user in the servlets anyone help me how to do that and give some piece of code thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Please be specific.. list the things you have tried and add some code for better answers..

Comment: thanks for your response actually i done designing part like a Facebook chat and the think is i do not have idea about business logic

Comment: For online Chat using Servlets, either you use long polling or Comet , Or Latest techonology Web Sockets.